# Spring REST, redirect request to another application with params (SSO, SAML)

Tags: java, spring, redirect, single-sign-on, saml

I must implement mechanism for SSO authentication based on SAML provider (in A app) and redirect to another application (B app) if the authentication is successeful. In the redirect I must include SAMLAssertion xml document (let's say encoded in base64) so I can authenticate in the another application (B app).

A app is Spring boot application with simple form for credentials. On form submit there is a REST call to SAML Idp and resposne is consumed. If the response is successful I am executing redirect to B app. HERE I would like to include response from Idp.

B app is complex Java application with own users database where I can implement custom authenticators based on HTTPServletRequests so I can consume both GET and POST requests. I would like to authenticate user in this app on the basis of saml resposne taken from A app. There are several reasons why B app cannot call IDp directly btw.

How can I pass SAML resposne to B app?
Is my approach correct in terms of SSO/SAML?

I know there are several questions related to this, however I could not find any resolution for my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing SSO/SAML you can use open source projects.Shibboleth and JOSSO are open source projects.They provide the implementation for both IDP and SP.

You need to configure IDP with LDAP,AD or database as needed.

Comment: I do have existing SAML IDp wokring. I am just responsible for creating new application which is going to be authenticated via SSO SAML with constraints describeed above.

Comment: You need to implement web services to get SAML resonse to SPs.First when a user want to access resource you need to redirect him to IDP application and when it is authenticated on IDP need to store the token against the user id to IDP database and then redirect to the SP server.You need to write web service code on SP server to fetch further user details from IDP.